# Using dependency parsing to predict custom entity labels

Tags: nlp, lstm, spacy

I'm looking for a way to use dependency parsing to improve the accuracy of predicting custom entity labels. Can someone point me to any resources? I have been googling and looking up documents mainly on spaCy but i haven't found anything useful.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already looked at [training dependency parser](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-train-parser)? You could produce dep parser training data which better relates tokens together. You can update the `deps` to relate token `A` to token `B` and define the relationship. Ie. token `A` has head at token `B` and the dep relationship is "CUSOTM"